# Check Status of All SQL Services

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, ssms, ssis, ssrs

I wanted to List all the SQL Services including Reporting Services.

```
Wmic service where (PathName like '%Binn\%sql%') get caption, name, startmode, state, PathName, ProcessId
```

This one will give all except SSRS. anyone have an idea how for that as well.

Comment: SimonS gives a good answer. If you want to know why SSRS was left out of your results, it seems to be because SSRS is installed in a `bin` directory instead of `binn`. (And this is why relying on a path is iffy. Microsoft, in future versions, is much more likely to change where an executable is installed than they are to change the name of the service.)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `wmic` and filter the Service Name instead of the path.

```
Wmic service where (Name like '%sql%') get caption, name, startmode, state, PathName, ProcessId
```

or in PowerShell (I'd suggest you to use this approach)

`Get-Service *sql*`

this will return all Services that have SQL in their name.

you can also use this from cmd like so: `powershell "Get-Service *sql*"`

Example Output:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-service *sql*

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  MSOLAP$SDFSF       SQL Server Analysis Services (XXXXX...
Running  MSSQL$SDFSDFS      SQL Server (XXXXXXXXXX)
Running  MSSQL$SDFSDF       SQL Server (XXXXX)
Running  MSSQLFDLauncher... SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launche...
Running  MSSQLLaunchpad$... SQL Server Launchpad (XXXX)
Running  ReportServer$BB... SQL Server Reporting Services (XXXX...
Stopped  SQL Server Dist... SQL Server Distributed Replay Client
Stopped  SQL Server Dist... SQL Server Distributed Replay Contr...
Stopped  SQLAgent$xxxxxx... SQL Server-Agent (xxxx1)
Stopped  SQLAgent$xxxxx     SQL Server Agent (xxxxx)
Running  SQLBrowser         SQL Server Browser
Running  SQLTELEMETRY$BB... SQL Server CEIP service (xxxx)
Running  SQLTELEMETRY$xxxxx SQL Server CEIP service (xxxxx)
Running  SQLWriter          SQL Server VSS Writer
Running  SSASTELEMETRY$B... SQL Server Analysis Services CEIP (...
```